# (ObjC -> Swift) SpriteKit : Create a new node (method "node")

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'd like to know how to convert the line just below in Swift :

```
GameLayer *gameLayer = [GameLayer node];
```

The main problem is that the method "node" doesn't exist in Swift! 
If someone could help me, it will be awesome!!

Comment: GameLayer is subclassing SKNode, right?

Comment: It's a subclass of SKScene

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your GameLayer class is a subclass of SKScene. You can initialize a scene like this:

```
let gameLayer = GameLayer(size: CGSizeMake(yourWidth, yourHeight))
```

Or as simple as this:

```
let gameLayer = GameLayer()
```